# How to use miniconda as a linux system user

Tags: python, django, miniconda

I'd like to run a Django app on a linux machine using miniconda as a tool for managing packages and virtual environment.

Systemctl will launch gunicorn as a dedicated system user, say my_app_user.
Sources will be on /opt/my_app with permission only for my_app_user.

What is the correct / secured way to install miniconda for such use case ?

Answer (score 0):

The approach I've used and seems to work is installing miniconda as the system user

First install conda as my_app_user

```
sudo su -c "sh Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh" -s /bin/sh my_app_user
```

Then create a virtual env as my_app_user

```
sudo su -c "/var/opt/my_app_user/miniconda2/bin/conda create --name my_env Django=4.1" -s /bin/bash my_app_user
```